# maven replacer plugin in not working

Tags: maven, maven-replacer-plugin

Here is the relevant part of `pom.xml`

```
 <plugin>
           <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
             <version>1.5.2</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
             <phase>pre-package</phase>
                 <goals>
                    <goal>replace</goal>
                  </goals>
                 </execution>
                </executions>
                    <configuration>
                       <file>target/swagger/api.json</file>
                <regex>false</regex>
                <token>$BUILD_NUMBER$</token>
                <value>${project.version}</value>
                        </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Here is `api.json` file

```
{
    "apiVersion": "$BUILD_NUMBER$"
    "developers": ["foo", "bar"]
}
```

After I run, `mvn clean package`, I do not see `target/swagger/api.json` being updated with `project.version`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your plugin declaration is in `<build><plugins>`

And not in  `<build><pluginManagement><plugins>`

Also, in case your project is part of a bigger maven project, it's safer to use ${project.build.directory} instead of target :

`<file>target/swagger/api.json</file>`

Answer (score 0):

1. think about the maven build phase upon you want to replace it, select a phase before u generate the docs with swagger f.ex. "validate" and set the swagger docs generation to "compile"

   2. exchange the $BUILD_NUMBER$ into %BUILD_NUMBER%
   3. Think about that this way you need to manually reset the value again to the %BUILD_NUMBER%